# How do i cache in gitlab ci while building docker images with docker:dind

Tags: docker, caching, gitlab-ci, docker-in-docker

I have a `gitlab-ci.yml` like this:

```yaml
build and push docker image:
  stage: publish  
  variables:
    DOCKER_REGISTRY: amazon-registry
    AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: ap-south-1
    APP_NAME: sample-app
    DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375
  image: 
    name: amazon/aws-cli
    entrypoint: [""]
  services:
    - docker:dind 
  before_script:
    - amazon-linux-extras install docker
  script:
    - docker build -t $DOCKER_REGISTRY/$APP_NAME:master .
    - aws ecr get-login-password | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin $DOCKER_REGISTRY
    - docker push $DOCKER_REGISTRY/$APP_NAME:master
```

This step takes 19=8 minutes to complete since the docker image steps are not cached. I want to be able to cache the before_script `amazon-linux-extras install docker` as well as the docker image I'm building.  We are running on our own gitlab runners. I've searched for answers but found 4 years old solutions. Is there a way to figure this out ? Also, will switching away from `docker:dind` help ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Gitlab CI cache doesn't work quite like that. If you have a job that installs npm dependencies, as an example, you could cache the resulting `node_modules` directory so `npm install` doesn't need to be run again, but it won't help for things like installing system packages.

Regarding the `docker:dind` service, you won't be able to run commands like `docker build...` or `docker push ...` without that service, even if you switched the image your job uses to `docker:latest`. It's a bit counterintuitive, but the only way to be able to run those commands is to use the docker-in-docker service.

However, you're not out of luck. I would recommend that you move the step in your `before_script` stage to your own docker image that extends `amazon/aws-cli`. As long as you have access to docker hub, Gitlab's included Registry (if using gitlab.com it's available, otherwise an admin has to enable/configure it), Amazon's registry (ECR I think?), or a privately run registry, you can create your own custom images and use them in Gitlab CI pipelines.

Here's an example Dockerfile:

```
FROM amazon/aws-cli
RUN amazon-linux-extras install docker
```

That's all you need to extend the existing `amazon/aws-cli` image and move your `before_script` installations to Docker. Once the file is done, run

```
docker build /path/to/dockerfile-directory -t my_tag:latest
```

After that, you'll need to login to your registry, `docker login my.registry.example.com`, and push up the image `docker push my_tag:latest`. If you're not using Gitlab's registry or the public docker hub, you'll need to configure your jobs or runners (either) so they can authenticate with your registry. You can read about that here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#define-an-image-from-a-private-container-registry

Next you just have to use it in your pipelines:

```yaml
build and push docker image:
  stage: publish  
  variables:
    DOCKER_REGISTRY: amazon-registry
    AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: ap-south-1
    APP_NAME: sample-app
    DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375
  image: 
    name: my_tag:latest
    entrypoint: [""]
  services:
    - docker:dind
  script:
    - docker build -t $DOCKER_REGISTRY/$APP_NAME:master .
    - aws ecr get-login-password | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin $DOCKER_REGISTRY
    - docker push $DOCKER_REGISTRY/$APP_NAME:master
```

One other thing you can do to save pipeline time (if it applies) is to only run this step when your Dockerfile has changed. That way if it hasn't but other jobs rely on it, they can just reuse the last image created. You can do that with the `rules` keyword along with `changes`:

```yaml
build and push docker image:
  stage: publish  
  variables:
    DOCKER_REGISTRY: amazon-registry
    AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: ap-south-1
    APP_NAME: sample-app
    DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375
  image: 
    name: my_tag:latest
    entrypoint: [""]
  services:
    - docker:dind
  when: never
  rules:
    - changes:
      - Dockerfile
      when: always
  script:
    - docker build -t $DOCKER_REGISTRY/$APP_NAME:master .
    - aws ecr get-login-password | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin $DOCKER_REGISTRY
    - docker push $DOCKER_REGISTRY/$APP_NAME:master
```

The root-level `when: never` sets the default for the job to never run, but the `rules` section checks to see if there are changes to the Dockerfile (accepts multiple files if needed). If there are changes, the job will always be run.

You can see details about the `rules` keyword here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rules

You can see details about custom docker images for Gitlab CI here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html

Comment: Be careful with "when: always" - this will run the job even if previous jobs failed. You will probably want to use "when: on_success" instead.

Comment: Not too sure about spaces in jobnames, BTW

Comment: Spaces in job names have always worked just fine for me @FabienHaddadi! The only caviat I've found is that when referencing them in say `needs` or `dependencies` you need to put them in quotes.

Comment: @Adam Marshall, so *not* totally fine then, albeit I was unable to find any job name convention online, I found it uncommon. Still, you've just admitted that some statements don't like it as such (quotes needed). I'm positive that if I used spaces in my company, I'd get heavily criticised ;-)

Answer (score 27):

One thing I have tried is to use cache layer in docker build. 
You could pull exist image from your registry, and then build with `--cache-from` parameter.

The job shell would be like this:

```
  variables:
    IMAGE_TAG: $DOCKER_REGISTRY/$APP_NAME:master
  script:
    - aws ecr get-login-password | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin $DOCKER_REGISTRY
    - docker pull $IMAGE_TAG || true
    - docker build --cache-from $IMAGE_TAG -t $IMAGE_TAG .
    - docker push $IMAGE_TAG
```

This method is mentioned in gitlab-ci [official document](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#make-docker-in-docker-builds-faster-with-docker-layer-caching) as well.

Comment: Thanks Carl, somehow I didn't realize you have to pull the image first ;)

Comment: I did all the above but Docker still installs dependencies from scratch. Is there any other way ?

Comment: I am not sure if there is other way. Maybe you could try the method in accepted answer.